# Show IP/MAC-address , running time/DNS server and logged in user name on desktop screen

Tags: ip

Is there a way to show the following things on the Desktop? Not like a warning but like text in the right top corner, not where the hour and network connections are in the panel, but really on the desktop. Like on top of the wallpaper.

- IP address
- MAC address
- Boot Time
- DNS server
- Name of logged in user

Comment: You mean "On Desktop" as in the area where wallpaper is ?

Comment: Hmmm, "text in top right corner". So it seems you want a unity panel indicator. That can be arranged

Comment: HI, no like you said first. LIke where the wallpaper is. But generated from the pc so not like an image and that doesn't change.

Comment: well, that could be possible with a custom widget of sorts. Conky could be a good point to start. I usually write my own stuff, so I'll probably try to do something like that and post. It's possible to generate a wallpaper with text "imprinted" onto the image,  but in my experience you can't continuously keep setting image over and over - it will eventually crash the desktop. So yeah . . . Look into conky for now. I'll see what I can do with a custom widget, but that probably will take time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your IP, you can use `indicator-ip`. Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bovender/bovender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-ip
```

It will look something like this:

[image: indicator-ip]

For the real username, install `dconf-editor` by running `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`. Once that's done, open up `dconf-editor`, and navigate to `apps` and then `indicator-session`. Look for `show-real-name-panel` and turn that on to `true` (it is false by default) and that will show your username.
[image: NameofUser].

For older releases, use `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true`.

If you would like to disable it, run `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false`

For the rest(and if you like you can do the IP as well), we can create our own indicators. We need to first install `sysmonitor`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

Open `sys-monitor`, and click on the Advanced Tab. We need to add a new script, so we click "New", thus we have this screen.

[image: Add-script]

In the Command Section, add your the required script you want to run. For example we will add the "Boot-Time" indicator.
So in the command we will write `uptime -s`. Add whatever description you want and name. Save it and look for your newly added script, and then click "Add". Your script should now appear on the topbar.

For example, here is the script to display the current CPU frequency for the first core:

```
echo $(grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '.' -f1) MHz
```

Here is the indicator

[image: CPU Speed]

## UPDATE

If you looking for your internal IP, create a script(as described above) and in the command box, add this:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'
```

That should get you the internal IP.

[WebUp8 Team - SysMonitor Reference](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/ubuntu-appindicator-that-displays-bash.html)

Comment: thnx a lot! Some of this is helping for other things. And maybe if what i meant isn't possible , you have the answers here :)

Comment: IP-indicator doesn't work :( has an error when installed with sudo apt-get install....

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10. The indicator with different scripts works fine but i need my ip adress and not the public one. That's why neither are working for me :(

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: @RUS I have added the line you need to get your internal IP.

Comment: HI, So i open Text editor. TOok the terminale code line u added and saved it in the home folder with name IP. I opend up sysmonitor and the advanced tab. CLick add, name Ip and sub Ip and command $HOME/IP. The IP file is exectuable made and works perfectly when i run it in the terminal.....

Comment: Does it have the executable permission? If not, you will need to add the permission by typing in the terminal `chmod 764 name_of_file` where `name_of_file` is the name of your file or path to the file.

Comment: It worked with the last update ! thx !!!